# Launch application in gdb with non-path name

Tags: path, gdb, argv

I am trying to launch a legacy application in GDB, and it requires that it's `argv[0]` value not contain anything other than alphanumeric characters.

Whenever I launch the program in GDB it seems that it expands the name to be the full path before running the program, so I get an error like (because it can't deal with the slashes):

"Cannot find /home/user/myapp ..."

Is it possible to run a program in GDB with a relative path, so that it will just see "myapp"?

Comment: Do you have either the [`argv0`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/argv0.1.html) command or a shell that supports the `-a` option to `exec` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, and bash. Is that a yes to the second?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, sorry, yes, I have exec -a. The problem is that GDB is doing the launching, not a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gdb normally runs target commands using the shell command line

```
    exec program_pathname program_arguments
```

But it has a [`set exec-wrapper`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#set-exec_002dwrapper) command that will change this to

```
    exec exec_wrapper program_pathname program_arguments
```

The *exec_wrapper* is often another command, but it can be an option that the `exec` command accepts.

Many shells (bash, zsh, ksh93) support a `-a` option to the `exec` command to set argv[0].

So, if your shell supports `exec -a`, you can do the following to invoke `/home/user/myapp` with argv[0]==`myapp`:

```
(gdb) set exec-wrapper -a myapp
```

Comment: So it works if I am doing it in gdb's terminal, but for some reason when I do it from the command file I am passing in it doesn't do anything. Ideas?

Comment: @soandos Can you clarify: is the command file a shell script that runs gdb, or a `.gdbinit` file, or something else?

Comment: I am running gdb like this: `gdb myapp -command=.tmp_gdb_myapp_cmds` The contents of the "command file" are things like: set environment, and run (and now this wrapper)

Comment: If it will help, I am more than happy to change that.

Comment: If I put the gdb commands in a file, then gdb runs myapp with the altered argv[0], but the command in the file after `run` always gets the error **Error in sourced command file**. I don't know why. Is that what you're seeing? If I invoke gdb as `gdb myapp -ex "set exec-wrapper -a foo" -ex run -ex quit`, then all is well, but I realize you don't want to have to run gdb with a zillion command-line options.

Comment: I am not seeing that because I left run as the last line in the file. Honestly, I think I'm just going to have the really long command line, store it in a file, and then execute it. Not idea, but it works. Thank you

Comment: This isnʼt working for me; I think because the `argv[0]` doesnʼt match what GDB expects, it isnʼt recognizing it as the exec call to look at.  Instead of stopping at any breakpoints, I get a full run of the program followed by the message `During startup program exited normally.` (or a variant if the exit code isnʼt 0).