# how to make gdb debug a linked program

Tags: gdb, lldb

For example, if we do

```
mkdir a
mkdir a/b
mkdir a/b/c
mkdir a/b/c/d
ln /bin/ls -s a/b/c/d/myls
ln a -s as
gdb as/b/c/d/myls
...
(gdb) r
Starting program: <mypath>/a/b/c/d/myls
^D
lldb as/b/c/d/myls
(lldb) r
Process 56636 launched: '<mypath>/as/b/c/d/myls' (x86_64)
```

We can see that gdb debugs on the canonical program, while lldb debugs on the linked program. How can we make gdb debug the linked program w/o getting its absolute path?

Comment: Related: [Launch application in gdb with non-path name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957892/launch-application-in-gdb-with-non-path-name)

Answer (score 0):

> We can see that gdb debugs on the canonical program, while lldb debugs on the linked program.

No, we don't see this. We see that GDB performs a `realpath` to resolve the program, and `lldb` doesn't, but they *both* debug the *exact same* program.

Comment: If in the executable we check the path of the executable, are they the same?

Comment: @JoeC Depends on what you mean by "check the path of the executable".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use hard links instead?

This way, gdb will always refer to what you are looking for.

You can also play with with different version of gdb. It seems that version 7.11 provides what you want.

Take a look here:

```
~/tmp/link] stat hello
  File: ‘hello’ -> ‘../hello’
```

This is what you get for version 7.12

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./link/hello...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

while for older gdb, you get

```
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from full_path/tmp/hello...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

So, play around with more recent release.